# VSCode User Input Method (Extension Development API)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How do you ask for a user input and store it in a variable in VSCode Extension? For example, something like below (I know it does not work)

```js
const userResponse = vscode.window.input("Type in your response")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`window.showInputBox`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.showInputBox).

```js
import { window } from 'vscode';

const userResponse = await window.showInputBox({
  placeHolder: 'Type in your response'
});
console.log(userResponse);
```